# MySQL / Eloquent greedy regexp

Tags: mysql, regex, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to query a MySQL table using Laravel's ORM Eloquent (kinda irrelevant I guess). I have a field in the table called `quantitative`, which contains a JSON in the format 
`[{name: 'a', value: 3}, {name: 'b', value: 4}]`.

I want the user to be able to query all the entries that contain values that he specified in whatever order.

```
AllowedFilter::callback('quantitative', function (Builder $query, $value) {
    $quantitative = collect($value)->filter(function ($el) {
        return isset($el['value']);
    })->pluck('value')->map(function ($el) {
        return "(?=.*{$el})";
    })->implode('');

    $query->where('quantitative', 'regexp', "({$quantitative}).*");
}),
```

that generate's query (below) using regex `(?=.*a)(?=.*b).*`

```
SELECT count(*) as aggregate from `table` where `quantitative` regexp ((?=.*a)(?=.*b)).* (...)
```

It produces the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1139 Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp

Regex itself is working just fine when I'm validating it at regex101.com, the issue I have is it's not valid for MySQL syntax. Is there any way to make it work or use different regex to accomplish the task?

Comment: If the MySQL is not v.8+, you can't use lookaheads in the pattern.

Comment: Just build the query using `LIKE`: `SELECT count(*) as aggregate from table where quantitative LIKE "%a%" AND where quantitative LIKE "%b%"....`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like either of these would work:

```
LIKE '%a%b%'

REGEXP 'a.*b'
```

Please provide a short list of strings that *should* match and a short list that should *not* match.

If you are trying to find things inside a JSON string, I suggest either

- Don't use JSON
- Use the JSON functions, if your version of MySQL is new enough.

REGEXP and LIKE are much too kludgy.  Note that `[{name: 'b', value: 4}]` contains both an `a` and a `b`.